# How to spawn in loop like snail but in square

Tags: c#, for-loop, mesh, terrain, procedural-generation

Hello I am French so excuse my bad English please,
I created a generation of land with a seed with prefabricated gameobjects but they spawn from column to column so I would like to create this but starting from the center to outside like a snail but in square

I partially succeeded, the first image shows the generation in columne but also the desired final result with the generation in snail and the second shows what I managed to do therefore in snail but my pieces of land are square it looks bad

- First:
  [image: 1]
- Second:
  [image: 2]
- It works like:
  [image: 3]
- And I want it Work like:
  [image: 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you start from the origin O and the other 4 directions are E,S,W,N

```
  N
W O E
  S
```

Then the step sequence you'll move is

```
E S
W W N N
E E E S S S
W W W W N N N N
...
```

You may notice that every time you turn twice, you need to increase the number of times you move in this direction by one.

Some pseudocode:

```
var dirs = new Vector3[] { E, S, W, N } // 4 directions
Vector3 pos = O; // origin

do
{
    var dir = 0
    var moveTimes = 1

    for (i = 0; i != 2; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j != moveTimes; ++j)
        {
            pos += dirs[dir]; // step forward
        }
        dir = (dir + 1) % 4; // turn
    }

    moveTimes++;
}
while(/* condition to stop */);
```

Comment: ok thx but now the problem is the finish, the map is like a snail but the last point is too much

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the solution but i think it's not the best solution

```html
for(int i = 0; i != Size; i++)
        {
            if(i == Size - 1)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y != moveTimes; y++)
                {
                    pos += dirs[dir];
                    GameObject inst = Instantiate(TileMap, pos, Quaternion.identity);
                    inst.GetComponent<MapGeneratorChunk>().ID = ++SetID;
                    inst.GetComponent<MapGeneratorChunk>().Seed = Seed;
                    print("hello");
                }
                dir = (dir + 1) % 4;
                for (int y = 0; y != moveTimes; y++)
                {
                    pos += dirs[dir];
                    GameObject inst = Instantiate(TileMap, pos, Quaternion.identity);
                    inst.GetComponent<MapGeneratorChunk>().ID = ++SetID;
                    inst.GetComponent<MapGeneratorChunk>().Seed = Seed;
                    print("hello");
                }
                dir = (dir + 1) % 4;
                for (int y = 0; y != moveTimes; y++)
                {
                    pos += dirs[dir];
                    GameObject inst = Instantiate(TileMap, pos, Quaternion.identity);
                    inst.GetComponent<MapGeneratorChunk>().ID = ++SetID;
                    inst.GetComponent<MapGeneratorChunk>().Seed = Seed;
                    print("hello");
                }
                dir = (dir + 1) % 4;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int x = 0; x != 2; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y != moveTimes; y++)
                    {
                        pos += dirs[dir];
                        GameObject inst = Instantiate(TileMap, pos, Quaternion.identity);
                        inst.GetComponent<MapGeneratorChunk>().ID = ++SetID;
                        inst.GetComponent<MapGeneratorChunk>().Seed = Seed;
                    }
                    dir = (dir + 1) % 4;
                }
                moveTimes++;
            }
        }
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79DOh.png)